# APEX 5: Page item (Select List) with LOV must have values from a another table which return PK (FK of current table)

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a page form where the user can make a new account. Every user has a type. The user must choose which type of user it is.
I have two tables (Users and UserTypes). What I want to do is user must choose the type from a select list which contains UserTypes.usertype in a table which has UserType_id a PK and FK in USERS.

How to make every value of that select list represent it's PK? Thanks.

[image: LOV and SOURCe of my page item]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your Select List type. Choose `SQL query` in `List of Values` section, as a source of a list write following:

```
select usertype, usertype_id from usertypes
```